# Oracle ResultSet.getString("colname") returning the string "null" instead of java null

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Edit: Subsequent checking of addrline2 (addrline2 == null) reveals that addrline2 is in fact null, printing out the null object resulting in the string "null" going to stdout.

I'm using the Oracle 11g thin client with an Oracle 11g database.  When querying a column that contains null, getString("colname") is return a string "null" instead of a Java null value.  Is that the expected behavior?  Javadoc indicates I should be receiving a Java null.

```
    ResultSet rs = descStatement.executeQuery();

    rs.next();
    String addrline2 = rs.getString("addressLine2");
    System.out.println("addrLine2->"+addrline2+"<-");

    boolean wasNull = rs.wasNull();
    System.out.println("Wasnull: "+wasNull);
```

output:

```
addrLine2->null<-
Wasnull: true
```

Comment: Are you sure the value in the column is not "null"? Do you have any kind of DB browser so you can be sure?

Comment: Yes, try `+(addrline2 == null)+`. String + calls String.valueOf(...)

Answer (score 7):

Note that a null object, when converting to a string, prints out as "null". You're not actually checking for null-ness anywhere.

Try adding

```
if (addrline2 == null) {
    System.out.println("It's null!")
}
```

Comment: you are correct.   I am getting back a Java null.  Thanks.  (I was using spring's BeanPropertyRowMapper and it is setting a String attribute to the string "null" so when I saw the null print out I thought I was getting the "null" from the driver, instead it it is the toString() of the Java null object.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

rs.getString("addressLine2") is returning null only but when yo do

```
System.out.println("addrLine2->"+addrline2+"<-");
```

its printing  null as string literal

do it like this

```
  System.out.println("addrLine2->"+addrline2!=null ? addrline2 : "Its null"+"<-");
```